# JavaScript: Error con .then e innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Tengo errores en el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 Id = "Datos"></h1>

        <script>
            fetch('http://localhost/API_PHP/backend/Datos.php')
            .then(Datos => Datos.json())
            .then(Datos => {
                document.getElementById('Datos').innerHTML = ´
                Dolar: ${Datos.Dolar} - Euro: ${Datos.Euro}
                ´
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Los errores estan especificamente en este script:

```
.then(Datos => {
document.getElementById('Datos').innerHTML = ´
Dolar: ${Datos.Dolar} - Euro: ${Datos.Euro}

})
```

Los simbolos  me dan error y las llaves de apertura `{` luego del `$` tambien y los : luego de `Euro` igualmente.

Me imagino esta mal la sintaxis, por favor agradezco me ayuden pues estoy comenzando jejeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el único error que tienes es tener las comillas al revés; prueba así y nos comentas:

```
document.getElementById('Datos').innerHTML = `Dolar: ${Datos.Dolar} - Euro: ${Datos.Euro}`
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button type="button" onClick="alerta()">Click</button>
  </body>

<script>
  function alerta(){
    var texto = 'Mensaje';
    alert(`${texto}`)
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Exelente amigo, eran las comillas al reves. Un simple detalle de sintaxis... Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenisimo! Si estas conforme con la respuesta, marcala como correcta para futuras referencias colega... Feliz código!

Comment: Listo amigo... ya la marque como correcta. Es de gran ayuda este site... saludos colega!